# setTimeout: почему элементы не выводятся по очереди

Tags: javascript

Элементы, по задумке, должны появляться с промежутком в 2000 ms. На деле все элементы появляются вместе (а не по очереди) через 2000 ms. Почему так происходит?

```js
var countNum = prompt("Введите сколько раз посторить", '');

var i = 0;

while (i < countNum) {

    function createTime() {
    }setTimeout(function () {
        createElementsInsideAndButton2();
        console.log("Содаёться элемент")
    }, 2000);
    i++;
}

function createElementsInsideAndButton2() {
    var colorArray2 = document.body.getElementsByClassName("container");
    for (var i = 0; i < colorArray2.length; i++) {
        var innerHtml = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            innerHtml += '<div class="element">Element</div>';
        }
        colorArray2[i].innerHTML += innerHtml;
        colorArray2[i].innerHTML += '</br>';

        var btn = document.createElement("input");
        btn.id = "btn";
        btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        btn.value = "+";
        colorArray2[i].parentNode.insertBefore(btn, colorArray2[i].nextSibling);
        console.log(colorArray2[i])
        console.log(btn)
    }
}
```

в Html вызываю функцию createTime()

```
<p onclick="createTime()" type="button">Внимание сейчас создасться div</p>
```

Comment: Исправьте `2000` на `i*2000`.

Comment: Потому что у вас все таймауты - "через 2 секунды от текущего момента", а не "через 2 секунды от предыдущего таймаута"

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Работает!!! Спасибо!!!

Comment: @Regent Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, у вас там пустая функция `createTime`, которая ничего не делает. Разберитесь с ней тоже)

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko я её вызываю в теге в html `<p onclick="createTime()" type="button">Внимание сейчас создасться div</p>`

Comment: Понятно. В вопросе она у вас пустая и ничего не делает.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Сейчас исправлю! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите: `setTimeout` добавляет переданную функцию в очередь коллбеков таймера. То есть функция выполнится **минимум** ( но нет гарантии, что точно ) через N миллисекунд, которые вы передали вторым параметром.

В данном случае у вас цикл, который добавляет в очередь несколько колбеков. То есть когда цикл закончится, в очереди будет уже несколько функций. Задержка же у всех функций одинаковая, поэтому функции выполнятся без задержки между друг другом

Исправленный вариант

```js
var i = 0;
var countNum = 10

while (i < countNum) {
  i++;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Создаётся элемент")
  }, i * 2000);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можете ещё в ответ, решение добавить, которое предложил  Stepan Kasyanenko (оно работает), так как ответ объясняет что я неправильно сделал а, как исправить нет.